# Label OCR text in an Image

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

This codepen demo [here](https://codepen.io/Maximusssssu/pen/XWBYVbo?editors=1010) reads **text from a web image URL** (Example: [here](https://i.ibb.co/ZfYdgqh/all-numbers.jpg) ) which also **displays its text position, for example the number 25 is between [178,183] and [193,183]** which has an **overall image size of 513 and 277** as stated in the console. So, I **have tried to label these positions  on image in another demo** [here](https://codepen.io/Maximusssssu/pen/MWBrggO?editors=1111), but it seems like the **bbox (boundary box) is out of position** is shown in my images below. **I am trying to highlight text on the image which was read by the OCR using a red rectangle.** May I ask how to resolve this issue so that the text are highlighted perfectly and not out of position? Any help will be appreciated :).

[image]

[image][image][image]

I have made sure the image in my demo is scaled to the correct sizes as stated by the console.

`<div id="reddot-container">`

`<img src="https://i.ibb.co/T8ZhGjr/num.jpg" alt="Map" class="img-fluid" width="513px" height="277px">`

`</div>`

Comment: In the 2 images of code above, you've highlighted the `baseline` variable. Since you want the ones for the bounding-box, you should get the `bbox` values instead.

Comment: @enhzflep, hi, yes, I have tried that too but its also out of position. I have tried everything haha :)

Comment: @enhzflep, I have also updated the values in my demo https://codepen.io/Maximusssssu/pen/MWBrggO?editors=1011